# MySQL - SELECT where multiple fields must be true

Tags: mysql

I don't know where to start with this!

I have a `product` table and a `product_attributes` table.  Each product can have multiple attributes.

If we work with just 2 attributes to keep things simple (id 1 = size, id 2 = colour), the `product_attributes` table looks like this:

```
id   product_id   attribute_id   value
======================================

1    1            1              10
2    1            2              Red
3    1            1              12
4    1            2              Red
5    2            1              10
6    2            2              Blue
```

So here we have 2 products, the first has 2 sizes (10 and 12) both in red.  The second is size 10 in blue.

I want to find all products where the size is equal to (10 **OR** 12) **AND** the colour is red.

```
SELECT * FROM product p INNER JOIN product_attribute a ON a.product_id = p.id WHERE (a.value = '10' OR a.value = '12') AND (a.value = 'red')
```

The above obviously isn't going to work but gives an idea of what I'm after.  I'm pretty sure I need a count in here somewhere (WHERE number of hits = 2) but I have no idea where to start.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `WHERE (a.value = '10' OR a.value = '12') AND (a.value = 'red')` is contradictory

Comment: Yeah I know... thats the issue

Comment: Suppose the colors for product 1 are red and blue, then how do you know if size 10 is red or blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product p 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
    FROM product_attribute pa1 
    WHERE pa1.product_id = p.id
        AND pa1.value in ('10', '12'))
AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
    FROM product_attribute pa2 
    WHERE pa2.product_id = p.id
        AND pa2.value = 'Red')
```

The question @SalmanA asked still applies.

Comment: This is perfect thank you! The example table I gave would never happen in reality, I just tried to keep it simple to explain my problem.  There are more tables involved.  Apologies for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery :

```
SELECT * 
FROM product p 
INNER JOIN product_attribute a ON a.product_id = p.id 
WHERE a.value = '10' OR a.value = '12'
AND p.id IN (
    SELECT p.id 
    FROM product p 
    INNER JOIN product_attribute a ON a.product_id = p.id 
    WHERE a.value = 'red'    
)
```